# c++ change global variable value in different files

Tags: c++, file, global-variables

i have some trouble with global variables. My task is to define a global variable in a header file whose value can be updated in other files. If i modify the value of the global variable in a file, i want that this updated value can be seen in all other files.

For example let's say i have 4 files: main.cpp constants.h server.h and server.cpp.

1. in costants.h i want the global variable of type int call myVar.

   `static int myVar=0;`
2. in main.cpp i include the header file and i call myFunction that is implemented in server.cpp

   `#include "constants.h"

   cout<<"myVar is:"<<myVar<<"\n";      // prints 0;
   myVar=3;
   cout<<"now myVar is:"<<myVar<<"\n";  // prints 3;
   void myFunction();`
3. in sever.cpp i include the constant header file and implement myFuntion()

   `#include "constants.h"

   void myFunction()
        {
             cout<<"myVar in server.cpp is:"<<myVar<<"\n";   //prints 0 not 3!!!
        }`

The problem is that here myVar is 0 while i would like it to be 3!

Answer (score 7):

If you define your variable as `static` it means that the scope of the variable is the file itself, or in other worlds, that there will be a variable created for each file in which you're including your header file. So `main.cpp` and `server.cpp` will each have their own instance of the `myVar` variable.

You can declare a variable in `main.cpp` and access this variable using the extern keywords:

```
// In main.cpp
int myVar = 0;

// In server.cpp
extern int myVar;
```

Another solution would be to put the extern declartion in your header, so you can access the variable in each file where you include the header. There is no conflict in declaring a variable as `extern int var` in a header file and declaring a variable `int var` in a file with an include to the header.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

i solved by declaring a global variable in the main like `int myVar=0;` Then in the other files i call and update this variable with extern statement like `extern int myVar=X;`

This procedure works only if the global variable is declared in the main since the compiler complain for declaring (in the header) the variable `int myVar=0;` probably because is expecting a "const" attribute or similar... 

Moreover following your last suggestion (`extern int myVar=0;` in the header and `int myVar=X;` in the other files) gets me an error of *"Multiple declaration of myVar"*

Comment: @user3589429 You misunderstood my last words. =) When I say "Put the `extern` declaration in the header.", it did not mean "Declare the variable in each file.". You declare the variable either in `main.cpp` OR `server.cpp` and put `extern` in the header.